# Возможно ли сжимать загружаемые изображения по весу?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Пользователи загружают свои изображения на сайт, они попадают в дирректорию на хостинге, т.е. хранятся все на хостинге. Возможно ли при загрузке сжимать изображения по весу?

Comment: Без потери качества и размеров - нет.

Comment: потеря качества приемлема, я понимаю, что без этого никак

Comment: ну тогда можно. думаю, будет лучше, привести все изображение к одному виду(размеры, качество). сам для этих целей пользуюсь библиотекой http://wideimage.sourceforge.net/examples/resizing/